# iOS Metal how to compute standard deviation in kernel function?

Tags: math, statistics, metal, ios14

I have a kernel Metal function, it receives an X,Y grid position of an element. I would like to apply statistical filtering to some elements, and need to know the standard deviation of the value from it's neighbors.

I can implement the function myself inside the kernel function, but am curious if there's a better/more efficient way.

**Does iOS Metal provide ready-made math functions that I can use to compute standard deviation of a small number (10 or so) members?**

Comment: Do you need this calculation for every element in the grid in respect to its surroundings? Or to one or a handful such elements out of a large grid?

Comment: every element (307000) of them in relationship to its closest neighbors (in a grid) - say 10 horizontal and 10 vertical samples per element.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look into the Metal Performance Shaders framework. There are dozens of image processing filters that may be of use, especially if you are doing a standard filter (e.g. Gaussian blur). For this particular problem, the `MPSImageStatisticsMeanAndVariance` image filter would probably be your best bet. After encoding the filter work and writing into some output texture (or `MPSImage`; see the docs linked below for more info), you would then access the variance and simply use the `sqrt` function on the variance value read in from each thread in MSL (each reading from the output texture). It might look something like

```
import MetalPerformanceShaders

let device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()!
let commandQueue = device.makeCommandQueue()!

let sourceTextureDescriptor = MTLTextureDescriptor.texture2DDescriptor(pixelFormat: .rgba8Unorm,
                                                                       width: 100, height: 100,
                                                                       mipmapped: false)
let sourceTexture = device.makeTexture(descriptor: sourceTextureDescriptor)!

let destinationTextureDescriptor = MTLTextureDescriptor.texture2DDescriptor(pixelFormat: .rgba8Unorm,
                                                                            width: 100, height: 100,
                                                                            mipmapped: false)
let destinationTexture = device.makeTexture(descriptor: destinationTextureDescriptor)!


// Do encoding work
let commandBuffer = commandQueue.makeCommandBuffer()!

// Create the `MPSImageStatisticsMeanAndVariance` filter
let filter = MPSImageStatisticsMeanAndVariance(device: device)

filter.encode(commandBuffer: commandBuffer, sourceTexture: sourceTexture, destinationTexture: destinationTexture)

// Do more work with the destination texture
let customEncoder = commandBuffer.makeComputeCommandEncoder()!
customEncoder.setComputePipelineState(...)
customEncoder.setTexture(destinationTexture, index: 0)
...
```

More documentation for the `MPSImageStatisticsMeanAndVariance` and MPS image filters can be found on the Apple developer website [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metalperformanceshaders/mpsimagestatisticsmeanandvariance) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metalperformanceshaders/image_filters) respectively. This may not be precisely what you are looking for, but there may be other resources in MPS of use